# Unzipping a .btbz2 file on Linux

Tags: linux, bzip2

I just started working on Linux and got my first challenge
I have this file under some directory and I guess it is a zip file I need to unzip can any one please tell how to unzip this **.btbz2**  file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use software for this kind of files. bzip2 packages is what you need

Comment: What kind of software, Isn't there any command which will do it..?

Comment: bzip2 - this is the name of the software

Comment: Was it a `tar`ball of a bzip2 file?